# Eclipse PHP Development for Magento

Tags: php, eclipse, magento

I am trying to install the PHP development environment so I can use the Magento plugin. I am not a PHP developer so I do not have PHPStorm.

I am having a lot of trouble with problems such as:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: PHP Development Tools (PDT) Smart Import 4.2.0.201611142355 (org.eclipse.php.importer.feature.group 4.2.0.201611142355)
  Missing requirement: PHP Development Tools (PDT) Smart Import 4.2.0.201611142355 (org.eclipse.php.importer.feature.group 4.2.0.201611142355) requires 'org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.12.0' but it could not be found

Error on Toolkit 0.1.6 install:
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Magento Developer Toolkit 0.1.6.201311011730 (pl.mamooth.eclipse.magento.feature.feature.group 0.1.6.201311011730)
  Missing requirement: PHP Development Tools (PDT) 4.0.1.201606232253 (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 4.0.1.201606232253) requires 'org.eclipse.dltk.core.feature.group 5.5.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: PHP Development Tools (PDT) 4.2.0.201611142355 (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 4.2.0.201611142355) requires 'org.eclipse.dltk.core.feature.group 5.6.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Magento Developer Toolkit 0.1.6.201311011730 (pl.mamooth.eclipse.magento.feature.feature.group 0.1.6.201311011730)
    To: org.eclipse.php.feature.group 3.0.0
```

I have tried to install PHP PDT 4.2, and Language tools multiple times.

Comment: you can use **netbeans** for Magento development

Comment: Project is already exist ? or else Netbean is best IDE

Answer (score 0):

The code you are trying to install requires at least version `3.12.0` of the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin. This version of the plugin is in Eclipse Neon (4.6). Trying to install in an older version of Eclipse will not work.

Comment: For my SuiteCloud IDE environment I was not getting content assist in the newest version of Eclipse Neon. I had to revert back to Mars 4.5